# How can i write this for two unsorted arrays code?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search, pseudocode

The idea of binary search works perfectly in the case of the sorted array. We can sort the `A[]` and for each value `A[i]`, search whether there is another value `K-A[i]` present in the array or not. Binary search performs searching in `O(logn)` which could help us to improve the time complexity.

**Solution Steps**

Sort the array `A[]` in increasing order
For each element `A[i]`, use binary search to look for `K-A[i]`.
If there exists a value `K-A[i]` in the array A, then return true.
If you didn’t find such a pair in the whole array , then return false.

**Pseudo Code**
'''

```
int find_sumPair (A[], n, K)
     {
       Sort ( A, n)
       for( i = 0 to n-1 )
       { 
          x = binarySearch ( A, 0, n-1, K-A[i] )
          if ( x ) 
          return 1
       }
     return -1
     }
```

'''

This pseudo code is just for an array, how if i want to check for pair in two unsorted array with a given sum which complexity time of the pseudo code should be O(nlogn)??

Answer (score 0):

The above method solves this problem in O(nlogn) time.
You can sort 1 array in: O(nlogn) time and than you can iterate over another array and perform binary search over sorted array to find K-A[i] which is O(logn) time, so total time becomes O(nlogn). So TC will be O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn).

You can solve this problem in O(n) time by using O(n) space, using a hashmap.

```
#Pusedo code
arr1 = [...]
arr2 = [...]
K = some_value
hashmap = {k: True for k in arr1}

for each_element in arr2:
    if K-each_element in hashmap:
        return "sum found of element [each_element, K-each_element]"
return "no such sum present"
```